# thmmarks in ntheorem causing trouble with numbers in equations

Tags: equations, numbering, theorems, ntheorem

[Edited according to the comments (thanks!), i.e. inserted a minimal non-working example]

I spent the entire day yesterday trying to figure out what is wrong with the following.

```
\documentclass[draft,twoside,openright,10pt]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:requirementByWeidemaier}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
\label{eq:weidemaierVectorValuedFspace}
\begin{split}
\end{split}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

And when I try to run pdflatex on it, I get the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '{eq:requirementByWeidemaier}
' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.18 \end{gather}
```

If I remove the option 'thmmarks' from the 'ntheorem' package, then it works. However, I need this option to end my proofs with qed.

I really hope somebody has an idea what is wrong (I perhaps should say that I use TexLive 2012).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Probably this is not the cause of the problem, but you should put the `\label` just after `\begin{gather}` and not after `\begin{split}`. Anyway, if you don't provide a [minimal (not) working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it is difficult to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to load the `ntheorem` package with the option `amsmath` also.

From the `ntheorem` documentation:

> **Activation of endmarks**: `[thmmarks]` enables the automatical placement
>   of endmarks (see 2.3); when using the `amsmath`-package, `[thmmarks]`
>   must be complemented by `[amsmath]` (see Section 3.2).

So, modifying your MWE to

```
\documentclass[draft,twoside,openright,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:requirementByWeidemaier}
\end{equation}

\begin{gather}
\label{eq:weidemaierVectorValuedFspace}
\begin{split}
\end{split}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

works fine.

Comment: Thank you. I just lost an hour on this. For fucks sake, why doesn't `ntheorem` emit a warning when you don't set this option (or just silently set it itself) but **just silently breaks everything**?